# Twitter-bootstrap collapse plugin with dynamic content

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to use a collapse plugin to show more details in a table row. ie. when user clicks more link in a row i want to show the elements in the next div and the option should turn to less content . When click on less content all extra details will have to be hidden.
How can i did this? My table contain n no of rows and for each row i want to apply this collapse effectusing twitter bootstrap
My table structre is more like

```
<tr>
    <td>col1</td>
    <td>col2></td>.....
    <td>More column
        <a class='morebtnclass btn btn-info'>View deails..</a>
        <div style="display: none">Div with detailed content about row</div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use -

```
<tr>
 <td>col1</td> 
 <td>col2></td>.....
 <td id='div-td-1'>More column
  <a class='morebtnclass btn btn-info' data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#div-td-1" href=".collapsible" >View deails..</a>
                    <div class="collapsible collapse">Div with detailed content about row</div>
 </td>
</tr>
```

BTW, Its really not hard to find out the required Html or css classes by simply diagnosing the Html with firebug or developer tools -

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/ - FireFox

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/index - Chrome

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565628(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565628%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - IE

https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/ - Safari

that is posted in the bootstrap documentation.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

Try to use your programming skills a bit, this will save you from a lot of questions to be asked in future.... :)

Comment: I agreed its possible to implement by following documentation easily. But in my case i want to do an alteration to existing behaviour. For it i am seeking help.I want to show details in one row at a time.not all the rows.Any help in that?

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly what you asked for, but I think a popover is a great way to show/hide long content inside a table cell, without affecting table layout: **Example: http://www.bootply.com/Uw4gJbtHte**

Javascript:

```
$('.too-long').popover()
```

HTML:

```
<td>This</td>
<td>That</td>
<td>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs too-long" data-content="Lots of details are hidden in this popover! It fits nicely over a table without affecting the layout." data-placement="bottom">Details...</a>
</td>
```